# How do I append a value to a row of a column in a data frame through a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas

To start, I have a function I made called GetWebsite(id). It takes one argument which is an ID number. That function isn't the issue and returns a website address for me. The problem I am having is after I get that website, I cannot write it to the new column in the dataframe.

The data I am using is company info with 100 columns or so. I've tried and tried, searched and searched and I'm just lost at this point.

Here is the code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('10_records.csv')
df['WebsiteURL'] = ''

for position, i in enumerate(df.Id):
    #GET THE JSON AND PROCESS THE RESPONSE
    print(f'Currently getting the JSON for {i}.')
    ID = GetWebsite(i)
    if not ID:
        print(f'No Domain Found for {i}')
    else:
        #APPEND THE FILE TO THE CSV AFTER ADDING IT TO THE DATAFRAME
        print(f'Appending the website ({ID}) to the file.')
        df.insert(position,'WebsiteURL',ID)


        #MOVE ON TO THE NEXT FILE AFTER A RANDOM SLEEP 
        print('Done. Moving on to the next record in a moment.')
        sleep(random.randint(0, 10))

#SEND EVERYTHING TO CSV FILE NOW
df.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
print('Project successfully exported to CSV.')
```

What I think I'm doing here is before the for loop, I'm adding that new column to the dataframe with blank values for each row.

Then in the loop I'm calling my GetWebsite function and it's returning the domain. That works as expected.

What I now want to do, is add that domain to the row and move on to the next. At the end when the loop is over, I want to export the data frame to a csv.

This is my latest attempt where I am obviously using Pandas incorrectly and trying to enumerate then use df.insert to get it in there. I've also tried df.at() and several other ways. I'm just losing it now.

EDIT: This is what I am going for...

```
Output Example:
   RCount  PCount  ...  Email_1                    WebsiteURL
0         1436          0  ...                 NaN  www.eachcompanieswebsite.com
1         1436          0  ...                 NaN  www.eachcompanieswebsite.com
2         1436          0  ...                 NaN  www.eachcompanieswebsite.com
3         1436          0  ...                 NaN  www.eachcompanieswebsite.com
4         1436          0  ...                 NaN  www.eachcompanieswebsite.com
5         1436          0  ...                 NaN  www.eachcompanieswebsite.com
6         1436          0  ...                 NaN  www.eachcompanieswebsite.com
7         1436          0  ...                 NaN  www.eachcompanieswebsite.com
8         1436          0  ...                 NaN  www.eachcompanieswebsite.com
9         1436          0  ...                 NaN  www.eachcompanieswebsite.com
```

Where eachcompanieswebsite.com is a unique website to the row.

NOTE: I added unnecessary comments to the code just to be super clear with my thinking because I'm a noob and clearly doing something that is probably very obvious.

Comment: Can you please copy and paste in input and expected output? Please see:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: Wouldn't `df['WebsiteURL'] = df['InfogropupId'].apply(GetWebsite)` work in this case? Alternatively just define a new function that includes the error handling and sleep time and pass it to the apply instead,

Comment: what does `GetWebsite(i)` do. Is the information already in the dataframe? or is it outside? I dont think you need to use a for loop at all.

Comment: can you share what InfogroupId has please?

Comment: @SeanC `GetWebsite(i)` is incorrect in that code. It should be just `GetWebsite` since you are passing the function itself.

Comment: instead should it be just a simple statement without loop. `df['WebsiteURL'] = df['InfogroupId'].apply(lambda x: GetWebsite(x))`

Comment: Try changing `df.insert(position,'WebsiteURL',ID)` to `df.loc[position,'WebsiteURL'] = ID`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try something like this please:

```
def website(i):
    ID = GetWebsite(i)
    return ID if ID else 'No website found'

df['WebsiteURL'] = df['Id'].apply(lambda x: website(x))
```

you dont need to do any for-loop. Just get the file loaded to a dataframe and then add these steps.

I think that's what you are trying to do with the loop.